# How to import and choose format/font for numbers in Latex documents?

Tags: tables, fonts, import

I would like to add huge tables to a Latex document and I would like the numbers to be similar to this style

[image]

1- What is this style or how it can be adopted?

2- Is there a more efficient way to import numerical values into a Latex document than copying and pasting (they are in .csv or .txt file)? A sample of data I have are like the following

```
      1.77535624862992e-09
      -1.6503831338225e-11
      1.42322204974969e-13
      -1.25754292545496e-14
      3.53124304517183e-14
      9.52322722659394e-14
      -5.37131689647326e-11
      1.35862997839542e-10
      2.09695836541009e-10
      3.98007235542205e-10
```

Comment: AFAICT, your questions are on two completely separate subjects; is this impression correct? In order to have a chance to say something meaningful regarding your second question, it would be most helpful if you provided some information about how or where the numeric data are stored. E.g.,, in a plain-ASCII file? In a spreadsheet? If it's in a spreadsheet, in which format? (.csv would he helpful...)

Comment: @Mico Yes I apologize they are kind of different questions. I thought I'd combine them rather than posting two separate questions. I've added the format of the numbers

Comment: Check out the [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple?lang=en) package for working with csv files.

Comment: It might help to know if the numbers are already in scientific/exponential format with the `E+...` in the csv or if you are hoping to convert them to that when displayed.

Comment: @frabjous I have added a sample of the numbers that I have

Comment: Are the γ₁, γ₂ and γ₃ numbers in separate files, or in the same file, comma separated, or …?

Comment: @frabjous hmm I don't have them really since this is a totally different table structure than what I want to do. My data file (be it txt or csv) would be just one column of numbers like what I included in the post, which I would like to just transfer to the second column of a two-column table in my Latex doc.

Comment: What's in the first column? I ask because tabular data is usually inserted row by row, not column by column, so it's hard to suggest how to script importing data into the second column without handling the first column at the same time. (Or would you prefer just an answer to question 1 and let you figure out question 2 using csvsimple or lua?)

Comment: @frabjous Oh okay i see no problem. In the first column we can take enumerated x's such that in row 1 we have $x_1 $ in the first column and $1.77535624862992E-09$ In the second column. Similarly in the second row we have $x_2$ and $-1.6503831338225E-11$ and so on until the last row $x_10$.  Thanks for taking the time and helping I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Question: Numbers in TT Font

It looks to me that the main thing you want for question #1 is to put the numbers in a teletype/monospaced font. This can be done in a variety of ways. You could just use `\ttfamily` outside the table to apply the default teletype font to the entire table (but inside a group so it doesn't affect the rest of the document). Then inside the table, you'd have to use `\textrm{...}` for any text you want in the regular font. Math mode will be unaffected.

Since you're dealing with numbers, I also recommend using the `siunitx` package, which allows you to consistently format numbers with the same number of decimal places, the same exponent sign, etc. Within tables, it also provides means for aligning numbers in columns at the decimal spot, and exponent symbol, etc.

With a monospaced font, the aligning may not matter so much, but I recommend using the package anyway.

For your data, for example, you could do the following. I provide comments for the siunitx column `S` options so you understand what they are; here it is important that we put the numbers in text mode inheriting the current text font without resetting it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\ttfamily
\begin{tabular}{%
>{\begin{math}}c<{\end{math}}% first column centered in math mode
S[% second column uses siunitx
output-exponent-marker = {\mathrm{E}},% use `E' as exponent marker
print-implicit-plus,% add + to positive numbers
reset-text-family=false,% use active text font (\ttfamily)
mode=text,% print as text
table-format=1.14e2,% one integer digit, 14 decimal digits, 2 exponent digits
minimum-decimal-digits=14,% pad to 14 decimal places
group-digits=false% don't put digits in blocks of 3
]}
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textrm{\textbf{X}}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textrm{\textbf{Value}}} \\
\toprule
x_1 & 1.77535624862992e-09  \\
x_2 & -1.650383133822e-11  \\
x_3 & 1.42322204974969e-13  \\
x_4 & -1.25754292545496e-14  \\
x_5 & 3.53124304517183e-14  \\
x_6 & 9.52322722659394e-14  \\
x_7 & -5.37131689647326e+11  \\
x_8 & 1.35862997839542e-10  \\
x_9 & 2.09695836541009e+10  \\
x_{10} & 3.98007235542205e-10 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

See the [siunitx user manual](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf) for more info.

The output looks like this:

[image: siunitx table with ttfamily]

### Second Question: Reading Data from External File

In the comments I recommended the `csvsimple` package; here I use its more recent "l3" version. It allows you to define "csvreader" commands that read data from a csv file. Your data doesn't have any commas in it, but technically it still counts as a one-column csv file, so the package still works.

The core command had the form

```
\csvreader[options]{filename}%
    {mapping of columns to commands}%
    {pattern of data to insert for each csv row}
```

Many of the options are specific for creating tables; see below for details. The filename is of course the name of the csv file to read from. The mapping in your case could just cover `1=\commandname` to give a name to the first and only column. And the pattern is what each row should generate.

In [its documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple-l3.pdf) there is an example that uses siunitx on page 48. Adapting it to recreate the table above, we get this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[l3]{csvsimple}

\begin{document}
\begingroup
\ttfamily
\csvreader[
    tabular = cc,
    no head,
    table head = \toprule \textrm{\textbf{X}} & \textrm{\textbf{Value}} \\ \midrule,
    table foot = \bottomrule,
    before reading = \sisetup{output-exponent-marker = {\mathrm{E}},
        print-implicit-plus,
        reset-text-family=false,
        mode=text,
        table-format=1.14e2,
        minimum-decimal-digits=14,
        group-digits=false},
]{data.csv}{1=\datanumber}{%
\(x_{\thecsvrow}\) & \tablenum{\datanumber}%
}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

This assumes you have a list of numbers saved as `data.csv`, which just looks like this:

```
1.77535624862992e-09
-1.650383133822e-11
1.42322204974969e-13
-1.25754292545496e-14
3.53124304517183e-14
9.52322722659394e-14
-5.37131689647326e11
1.35862997839542e-10
2.09695836541009e10
3.98007235542205e-10
```

(Note I changed a couple numbers from what you provided so you could see the `+` before exponents, and in the second row, padding the decimal places, automatically take effect in the output. If this is genuine data you'll want to change them back.)

The output is identical to the image above for the previous tabular.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer.

Comment: @frabjous Hello. I am not the OP. I tried to adopt your table style, but it fails to show zero exponents for numbers like 3.98007235542205e-00. Is there any work around that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Morcus You can add `print-zero-exponent=true,` to the options for the S column. The package has a zillion options, however, and I can't summarize all of them. I recommend reading the [siunitx documentation](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/siunitx/siunitx.pdf), which is quite extensive.