How to format numbers in monospaced (typewriter) font using siunitx?
How to format numbers in monospaced (typewriter) font using siunitx?
MY CODE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    color = red,
    mode = text,
    number-color = blue,
    text-series-to-math = true,
    %??? numberFont = monospaced %???
}


\begin{document}
    
  \qty{42}{\meter}
    
  How can I define the number 42 in monospaced (typewriter) font in the sisetup,
  so that the number looks like this: \texttt{42}?
    
\end{document}


OUTPUT:


Edit:
I attempted an alternative approach, but it doesn't work as expected. Why?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    
    \texttt{\num{42}}\unit{\kelvin}
    
\end{document}


Output:


Hope this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659432/how-to-import-and-choose-format-font-for-numbers-in-latex-documents/659505#659505 will helps you

hey madymuvi, thx for reply, unfortunately i do not know how this link helps. Can you give me a hint?thx and best regards

siunitx aims to provide consistent formatting: here you text is not in monospaces, so numbers shouldn't be either ....

THX Joseph, ok is there any other possibility to change the number to monospace font ?

if you don't use a package designed to ensure consistent formatting, you can be as inconsistent as you like ;). since your example shows you already know how to do it, I assume you really want to know something else ...

If you are happy to print in text mode, you can apply additional formatting to the output:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{mode = text, text-font-command = \ttfamily}
\begin{document}

Some text \qty{42}{\K}.

\end{document}

If you want to apply only to numbers (even more inconsistent!)
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{number-mode = text, text-font-command = \ttfamily}
\begin{document}

Some text \qty{42}{\K}.

\end{document}


THANKS Joseph it works! :) Only a tiny thing: the font of the unit is also monospaced. Could you change this to standard text font (or any other font then monospaced), so that only the number is in monospaced font? best regards

Hope this will helps:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmonofont{TeX Gyre Cursor}
%\setmonofont{courier}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\newfontface\tablefont{TeX Gyre Cursor}[Numbers={Tabular}]

\usepackage[text-rm=\tablefont, detect-all=true]{siunitx}


\sisetup{
    color = red,
    mode = text,
    number-color = blue,
    text-series-to-math = true,
    reset-text-family=false,
}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\unitdef}[2]{\bgroup\ttfamily\qty{#1}{#2}\egroup}%
    
\unitdef{42}{\meter}
    
  How can I define the number 42 in monospaced (typewriter) font in the sisetup,
  so that the number looks like this: \texttt{42}?
    
\end{document}

Please use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX for compilation
